# Like AWS Device farm desktop browser testing service, what service is available in GCP

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, aws-device-farm, google-cloud-test-lab

We have an AWS service Device farm desktop browser testing service to execute front end selenium automated testcases using boto3.

Is there any similar service available in GCP? to execute selenium testcases.

Comment: Have you checked [article 1](https://www.g2.com/products/aws-device-farm/competitors/alternatives), [article 2](https://sourceforge.net/software/compare/AWS-Device-Farm-vs-Firebase-vs-Google-Cloud-Run-vs-pCloudy/)

Answer (score 0):

For testing on (virtual and physical) mobile devices, [Firebase Test Lab](https://firebase.google.com/products/test-lab) sounds like the closest equivalent.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But , I am looking for something similar to device farm desktop browser testing to execute selenium testcases with python.

Comment: @S_G Do have any specific questions related to onboarding on AWS Device farm desktop browser testing service ?

Comment: @geek2geek_AWS  
 
I have one, which is not related to the currect topic. (Its diffuclt to find required test execution with session id. How to to find a perticular session? can we name the session?)